# CodeIgniter DataMapper table name override not working

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, datamapper

I have just set up DataMapper with CodeIgniter and written the models as required.

However I seem to have missed something, as when I run a query, DataMapper cannot see the table name override and thinks there is no table at all.

Funny thing is, if I remove the override, it works as it should (albeit with an error saying the auto-generated tabled doesnt exist).

Model Code:

```
class Activity extends Datamapper {

var $table = 'activity_log';

var $has_one = [
    'user'
]; 

}
```

Controller Code:

```
$activity = new Activity(1);
```

Error:

```
Error Number: 1064 
You have an error in your SQL syntax;
check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
syntax to use near 'WHERE `.`id` = 1' at line 2

SELECT * WHERE `.`id` = 1
```

As I mentioned above, if I remove var $tables = 'activity_log'; then it will defer back to looking for table 'activities' as it should.

Answer (score 0):

> Rules
>
> DataMapper models must be named the singular version of the object
>   name, with an uppercase first letter. So for a user object, the
>   DataMapper model would be named User. The model should have a
>   corresponding table in the database named as the lowercase, pluralised
>   version of the object name. So for a DataMapper model named User, the
>   table would be named users. For a DataMapper model named Country, the
>   table would be named countries.
>
> In most cases, the difference between the singular and plural version
>   of an object name is just a matter of adding the letter s on the end.

Your model should be named as `Activity_log`.

[Docs](http://datamapper.wanwizard.eu/pages/models.html#rules).

Comment: Unfortunately, this did not fix anything. even with model name as `activity_log` and the model being changed to `Activity_log` it still fails. I am aware of how datamapper normally refers to databases, but I am also aware of overriding this behaviour (with `var $table = 'activity_log')`. My issue is that when the override is present, the table is being set to `null` before the query happens.

Comment: `var` is deprecated keyword. Try with `public` (visibility) keyword instead.

Comment: Nothing changes I am afraid.

Comment: Does DataMapper interpret underscore as concetinating string between joining tables? What if table and class are named as `activitylog`?

Comment: I know from another project I'm working on that Datamapper can support underscores in table names. I do not wish to change any table name as that was undermine the entire point of the override.

Comment: Fair enough. I am using [Avenirer](https://github.com/avenirer/CodeIgniter-MY_Model)'s `MY_Model` that allows various interactions with db tables.